# Reading the dyno Metadata in the Vue store when deploying to Heroku

Tags: javascript, heroku, vue.js, environment-variables, vuex

How can you read the dyno metadata environment variables from the store?
I would like to do something like this:

```
export default {  
  state: {
    version: {
      heroku: process.env.HEROKU_RELEASE_VERSION || 'not defined',
    },
    error: '',
  },
```

I have only been able to read `VUE_APP` environment variables but the heroku dyno [metadata variables](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-metadata) all start with `HEROKU_` and you can't read them in the vue store.

Comment: has my answer solved your problem?:)

Comment: I will get beck to you if it works, will try later today!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use environment variables on frontend code then you have to use `EnvironmentPlugin`.

Add the following plugin to your `webpack` config:

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin([
    'HEROKU_RELEASE_VERSION',
  ]),
]
```

After that you can access to this environment varibale on frontend as you tried:

`process.env.HEROKU_RELEASE_VERSION`

Comment: because we use vue-cli-3 we don't have a `webpack.config.js`. Do you know how to add webpack plugins when webpack is not a dependancy

Comment: made a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53630205/using-a-webpack-plugin-with-vue-client-3