# Using a webpack plugin with Vue Client 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I want to use a webpack plugin in Vue using vue-cli but I don't want to install webpack, because Vue handles this...

Using [this](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#simple-configuration) example, I try to use the [Environment](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/) plugin from webpack.

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new EnvironmentPlugin([
        'HEROKU_RELEASE_VERSION']),
    ],
  },
};
```

But because we use vue-cli, I get :

> EnvironmentPlugin is not defined

When I include the webpack requirement

```
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin([
        'HEROKU_RELEASE_VERSION']),
    ],
  },
};
```

I get :

> Webpack should be listed in the project's dependencies. run npm install ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to install webpack as dependency.

`npm i --save-dev webpack`

After that add the following to your `vue.config.js`.

```
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin([
        'HEROKU_RELEASE_VERSION',
      ]),
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: No need to install webpack, it comes with vue-cli by default

Answer (score 12):

The answer above is good. I got another one here, with building condition control.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
 configureWebpack: (config) => {
   if(process.env.VUE_APP_BUILD !== 'development'){
     // do something...
   }
   config.plugins = [
     ...config.plugins, // this is important !
     new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/) // new plugins...
   ]
 }

};
```

Comment: This answer is much better as it's lazy and get ENVs injected

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks